# left join a column with array in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I have several tables 1 contacts and multiple data.

Contacts has an ID field and a Name field; Data has a field called Contacts (as well as other fields).

e.g Contacts

```
ID - Name
1 - James
2 - Mark
3 - Doug
```

e.g. data

```
ID - Contacts - Data
1 - 1,3 - more data
2 - 2 - more data
3 - 2,3,1 - more data
```

Obviously, the comma-separated numbers link to several people in the contacts table. How can I convert from the comma-separated list to the people's names? A standard left join won't work.

Is there a way I can do it in the original query or would I have to add a while inside a foreach inside my original while loop? Such as (the following doesn't work either but it's as far as I've got):

```
//original query while {
        $contacts_array = array(implode(",",$db['Contacts'])); 
        foreach ($contacts_array as $contacts_id) 
        { 
            $contacts_query = "SELECT Name FROM data_contacts WHERE ID='$contacts_id'";
            $contacts_result = mysql_query ($contacts_query);
            $contactslist="";
            while($contacts=mysql_fetch_array($contacts_result)){
                $contactslist .= $contacts['Name'].", ";
            } 
        } 
echo $contactslist;
}
```

Comment: Read up on 'normalization' and 'normal forms' (such as Boyce-Code Normal Form or BCNF).  Properly normalized tables, as recommended in the accepted answer, avoid the problems that your thoroughly denormalized `Data` 'table' (it isn't even in 1NF, so calling it a 'table' is a serious misnomer) shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always stored many-to-many relationships with individual rows instead of comma-separated values:

```
ID - Contacts
1 - 1
1 - 3
2 - 2
3 - 2
3 - 3
3 - 1
```

Comment: You should change your statement to: You must always... Otherwise I fully agree.

Comment: There is other data in the table so i dont think having separate rows is not an option at the moment.

Comment: @user122642 That is where an additional intermediary table would come into play.  A `data_contacts` table, with `data_id` and `contact_id` as the fields.

Comment: Then you should extract this in a separate table! Any other solution will be a mistake and come back to haunt you in the future!

Comment: I crated the extra tables. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). However, you should really rethink your table structure as MrSlayer suggested. That's the proper, relational, way to store a many to many relationship.